# Place Text input on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have divs with image inside it and also have textbox. What i want to do is when type something in text box and while i am typing the same should be displayed in image with the user defined font-face. Is it possible using js/jquery? Thanks.

Comment: You can JavaScript and CSS. What you have tried so far?

Comment: can you show some code you already created? yes that is possible

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/WxmQR/1/
 look at this example. I want to do the same with my own defined font-face.

Comment: Note that the example you gave us is created using HTML5 and this code will not work with all browsers.

Comment: look at the code i posted. I am using IE10. So complexity wouldn't matter. All i want to know is how do i define Font Face of my choice while typing text on image?

Comment: @user1670654: See my answer below with a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I've created a demo for you.

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/zeJxR/)

**HTML:**

```
Title: <input type="text" id="txtbox_title" />
<br/>
<br/>
Text: <textarea id="txtbox_para" ></textarea>

<div id="imageContainer">
    <h1></h1>
    <p></p>    
</div>​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#txtbox_title").on('keyup', function(){
    var value =  $(this).val();
    $("#imageContainer h1").html(value);
});

$("#txtbox_para").on('keyup', function(){
    var value =  $(this).val();
    $("#imageContainer p").html(value);
});
```

​

Comment: Perfect. Rest i'll figure it out myself. Thanks!

Comment: Good one, than after i will save this image save as it is possible.

Comment: @A.K. - This helps me to type text in the format i choose. but then when i right click on it. The text i typed should be saved as an image. As i am going to take transparent background.

Comment: @user1670654: Are you using [**cufon**](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/) or [**TypeFace**](http://typeface.neocracy.org/) for custom fonts?

Comment: i am taking a plain white image as background and i type something on it. I should be able to save the whole as an image.
I am not using any custom fonts. Just the regular once. Try running your own code and saving it as an image.

Comment: Oh, ok for this you need to use some jquery plugins...

Comment: I found the answer. I am posting it for those who might face this situation in near future.

    http://jsfiddle.net/WxmQR/50/

Comment: @A.K- Check the above demo. That inserts my text on image. Similarly i wanted to add one more image so that when i type something i should get output as two images with different font-face.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any of the jquery plugin available for this.
look into this plugin http://code.google.com/p/jquery-image-annotate/

working demo here- http://flipbit.co.uk/jquery-image-annotation.html